# React useEffect and mousedown listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a modal that closes if user clicked **outside it**.

**approach one** - passing `isModalOpened` so the state updates on click only if `isModalOpened` is true.

```
const [isModalOpened, toggleModal] = useState(false);
const ref = useRef(null);

const clickOut = (e) => {
  if (!ref.current.contains(e.target) && isModalOpened) {
     toggleModal(false);
  }
};

React.useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('mousedown', clickOut);

  return () => {
     window.removeEventListener('mousedown', clickOut);
  };
}, [isModalOpened]);
```

**approach two** - removing the `isModalOpened` from the dep array.

```
const [isModalOpened, toggleModal] = useState(false);
const ref = useRef(null);

const clickOut = (e) => {
  if (!ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
     toggleModal(false);
  }
};

React.useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('mousedown', clickOut);

  return () => {
     window.removeEventListener('mousedown', clickOut);
  };
}, []);
```

**Question**: should I pass or not to pass the `isModalOpened` to the dep array?

Comment: A little tip if your creating dialogs, don't use window, but instead place a full screen fixed transparent div, or semi transparent div, and attach the events to this.  Why?, because it allows you to have dialogs within dialogs...

Answer (score 1):

You do not need it.

The reason being that if you `toggleModal` to the same `false` value it will not cause a re-render.

So you do not need to guard against the value of `isModalOpened` which leads to not including the variable in you function, which leads to not requiring the dependency at all.

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't pass `isModalOpen` to the deep array because in this case your effect will just remove and add again the listener. It is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

Approach one will run the hook every time `isModalOpened` changes, removing the global listener when the modal closes. Approach two will run the hook when the component is (un) mounted, meaning the global listener will be active throughout the component lifecycle.

The answer depends on how you're planning to use the component. I'm guessing you plan to mount the component before the modal is opened (hence the `false` initial state), which means your 2nd approach will listen to the `mousedown` event from the moment the component is mounted to the moment it's unmounted. This approach would be valid if you were planning to mount the component only when the modal is opened. But you're not, which means you should set the global listener only when the modal is opened.

1st approach is correct.

*edit

But you can remove the `isModalOpened` check in your if statement.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. So two answers are for removing the dependency, and your answer is for keeping it.

Comment: The two answers are talking about the `isModalOpened` check in your if statement, my answer, however, is correct.

You can check this by inspecting global listeners in your browser's dev tools (or, simpler, by using console.log and checking when the `clickOut` function is invoked).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a bit different approach towards this. I would here wrap the `clickOut` function in `useCallback` which have dependencies as `toggleModal` and `ref` and have `clickOut` as dependency in `useEffect`. In this way whenever you `ref` or `toggleModal` changes, you have a new reference for `clickOut` and if you have new reference for `clickOut` you listeners will be assigned again in `useEffect`. This will help you will unnecessary `clickOut` function creation on each render and optimize the rendering as well.

So your code as per my suggestion will look like this:

```
const [isModalOpened, toggleModal] = useState(false);
const ref = useRef(null);

const clickOut = useCallback((e) => {
  if (!ref.current.contains(e.target) && isModalOpened) {
     toggleModal(false);
  }
}, [isModalOpened, ref]);

React.useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('mousedown', clickOut);

  return () => {
     window.removeEventListener('mousedown', clickOut);
  };
}, [clickOut]);
```

Comment: I like it, seems like the best solution. I wish somebody very experienced in react could confirm. Like CertainPerformance